# How does Notes app on iOS 13 do sharing for entire folder? How New CloudKit Container is probably used?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, ios13, mirroring

I have been trying to create something similar to the notes app in iOS 13 the notes app in the new iOS allows for the entire folder to be shared with other users. Apple claims that the use cloud kit for the own apps as well I wonder how they have used CloudKit in new notes app to allow for sharing of entire folder.Let’s assume the fact that they might use some internal API is not the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what Apple is doing, but I have a guess.

They probably have two record types: `Folder` and `Note`. Each `Note` will have its parent record set to a specific `Folder`.

They then use a `CKShare` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckshare)) to share the `Folder`, and [by definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/1640527-parent), that means all the child `Note`s automatically get included in the share along with the `Folder`.

If you are unfamiliar with how to use `CKShare`, I've always liked this tutorial (which is already a couple years old, though): https://medium.com/@adammillers/cksharing-step-by-step-33800c8950d2

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the overall sharing mechanism is well documented and understood, what is not clear is how to combine the sharing with the new CloudKit container in iOS 13.